# can't change v_dear in feuseregister

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to override the v_dear Marker in the feuserregister extention.

I tried this:

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.de.v_dear = Sehr geehrte {tca:gender} {data:title} {data:last_name}
```

I use typo3 6.0.6 and the feuserregister extention version is: 3.0.1

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these gender specific labels:

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1._LOCAL_LANG.default {
    v_dear_male = Dear Mr. {data:last_name},
    v_dear_female = Dear Mrs. {data:last_name},
}
```